# Why am I unable to access my Mongo collection in a React component?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, reactjs

Using `reactjs:react` as the official react package isn't installing correctly for Windows yet.

Just trying to get to grips with React and getting pretty frustrated by what seem to be small things. For some reason I can't actually query any of my Mongo collections via my React components - the basic Mongo queries in the Chrome console work as expected...

```
var ExampleComponent = ReactMeteor.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  //didn't think the following was necessary, but tried it to no avail:
  startMeteorSubscriptions: function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('exampleCollection');
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var collection = ExampleCollection.find().fetch();
    console.log(collection); //Empty Array []
    console.log(ExampleCollection); //Mongo Collection
    console.log(ExampleCollection.find()); //Cursor
    console.log(ExampleCollection.find().fetch()); //[]?? wtf? 

    this.setState({data: collection});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div data={this.state.data}>
        Hello World?
      </div>
    );
  }
});

Meteor.startup(function() {
  React.render(<ExampleComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
})
```

So what's going on here? Any help would be appreciated, I'm not finding as many resources about doing the basics with React and Meteor that I had hoped.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? setState just causes a re-render, but as state.data doesn't affect what is displayed I don't think the display would change?

Comment: `fetch` and `find` are both asynchronous. So, there aren't results when you call `setState`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reactjs:react, you need to implement a method: `getMeteorState()`
This is what sets your data to be available in your component when `render()` is called. You still should implement `startMeteorSubscriptions` if you're doing pub/sub with your data (which you did correctly).

For example:

```
var ExampleComponent = ReactMeteor.createClass({
  // Methods specific to ReactMeteor
  startMeteorSubscriptions: function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('exampleCollection');
  },
  getMeteorState: function() {
    return {
      data: ExampleCollection.find().fetch()
    };
  },

  // React Methods
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {};
  },
  render: function() {
    var data = this.state.data;

    return (
      <div>
        {/* Present your data here */}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```